# How do I convert this simple scriptlet to JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following scriptlet that I'm trying to convert to JSTL

```
<%
String req = request.getParameter("loginfailed");    
if(req != null)
{
    if(req.equals("true"))
    {%>     
    <h4 id="loginerrormessage">Invalid email address or password.</h4>          
    <%}
}
%>
```

This scriptlet works just fine, but I'm trying to convert it to JSTL now which I am new to.  This is my best attempt at recreating the logic using JSTL.

```
<c:set var="req" value="${request.getParameter(\"loginfailed\")}"/>
<c:if test="${ req!=null }">
    <c:if test="${ req.equals(\"true\") }">
        <h4 id="loginerrormessage">Invalid email address or password.</h4>
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

When I replace the scriptlet with the JSTL I have written above, nothing crashes but I no longer see the "Invalid email address or password." when I would have seen it using the scriptlet.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Is it a scope issue?  I figured the default page scope was fine for the c:set. Could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using escape quotes in the JSTL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
    <c:if test="${ param.loginfailed eq 'true' }">
        <h4 id="loginerrormessage">Invalid email address or password.</h4>
    </c:if>
```

here `param` is implicit JSP object which gives you access to request parameters.

Comment: Those two `<c:if>`s can be further simplified into a single `<c:if test="${param.loginfailed}">`

Comment: @BalusC : yes forgot EL is generous about nulls :). But `loginfailed` is a request param, will it be implicitly converted from String to boolean ?